# Delete a new variable passed into a function C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, sfml

I have the following code:

```
    shipVertices = { //This is going to cause a memory leak
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(0, 0)),
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(.2, .4)),
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(.15, -.8)),
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(0, -1)),
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(-.15, -.8)),
            new sf::Vertex(new sf::Vector2f(-.2, .4))
    };
```

In my destructor it is trivial to delete the `sf::Vertex`'s that make up `shipVertices`. How do I delete the `new sf::Vector2f(x, y)` that I pass into those constructors?

Do I even need to delete those? I thought that they might be handled internally somehow.

Comment: `Vertex (const Vector2f &thePosition)`, you dont need to new them to pass them in, just pass in `sf::Vector2f(0., 0.) ...`(temporaries)

Comment: looks like java expressed in c++11

Comment: Can you answer as a reply so I can accept that as the answer?

Comment: Um, if you are talking about [this sf::Vector class](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Vertex.php), there is no constructor that takes a plain pointer, which would make your code incorrect. Can you point to the documentation of `sf::Vector` that you're using?

Comment: I'm using the documentation for version 2.1, I get what Galik said, he answered my question right. I work in a java shop, so I have a bad tendency to mix the syntax of the two.

Comment: @Yakk whoops I totally misunderstood the question. I'll delete my comment :)

Comment: @Galik cayle thinks your answer solved the problem.  I still think that the code written above, with a deterministic delete, is a sign of abysmal code design.

Comment: You have to mention @TheOne otherwise he won't get a notification AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the API from sfml documentation, the constructor for sf::Vertex is `Vertex (const Vector2f &thePosition)`, which expects a constant reference (so you can pass in temporary too). You try to provide it with pointer, which is the result of calling the `new` operator, hence it shouldn't even compile.

So no you don't need to destroy the Vectors, since you don't need to dynamically allocate them at all.